# How to trap parsing error in JSON data

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Let me re-phrase my question. I need to parse JSON data from Last.FM. This data can change depending on the success of the lookup which means that my JSONP nodes could be different from one search to the next. Problem is if I lookup a node that doesn't exist the whole lookup fails and I loose all data in the JSON object. I don't know how to trap this kind of error and continue traversing the JSON data after the error.

```
/********** Last FM Scrobbler - get album JSON details ***********/

function refreshArtwork(artist, track) {    
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
  data: {
        method: 'track.getInfo',
        api_key: 'c88cc53549bec0e9f246f056dc05a745',
        artist: artist,
        track: track,
        format: 'json',
        },
  dataType: 'jsonp', //must be JSONP for CORS
  error: lstError, 
  success: getLastfm
   });
}



/* success: parse album XML from LastFM scrobbler */
function getLastfm(json) {

//alert(json.track.wiki.summary); // wiki summary
var lstArtist = (json.track.artist['name']); // artist
var lstTitle = (json.track.name); // Title
var lstAlbumart = (json.track.album.image[3]['#text']);// 0=small, 1=medium, 2=large,    3=xlarge
//var listWikis = (json.track.wiki.summary); // WIKI summary
var lstAlbum = (json.track.album.title); // album

// if no artist info then error in name
if (lstArtist ===null) {
    $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + 'No Artist Match on Last.FM!' + '</li>');
    lstError();
}
// if no album art info then error in album URL
if (lstAlbumart ===null) {
    $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + 'No Album Art URL Match on    Last.FM!' + '</li>');
    lstError();
}
```

For example if the album title is missing in the JSON data I can't get to any of the other nodes. lstTitle = (json.track.name); if its missing the others won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof` to check for the existence of a node.

Something like:

```
var lstArtist = (typeof json.track.artist.name === "string")
                ? json.track.artist.name
                : '';
```

This will set the `lstArtist` variable to either the artist's name or a blank string if that does not actually exist.

The great thing about `typeof` is that it always returns a string, even if what you're checking doesn't exist (in this case it returns the string: "undefined").

Check-out some documentation for `typeof` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Note the above code is just a ternary operator (short-hand if/then statement). Docs here for ternary operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: thanks looks like what I've been searching for... how to test a node to see if its there before it breaks the whole JSON I thought I was in a catch-22 moment!

Answer (score 0):

I am perplexed... I continue to have trouble testing the returned JSON values against "" or null or undefined without success. As soon as one of the nodes is not part of the JSON object all the data is simply not returned. the challenge is that the JSON will change depending on the search results.

```
/********** Last FM Scrobbler - get album JSON details ***********/

function refreshArtwork(artist, track) {    
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
  data: {
        method: 'track.getInfo',
        api_key: 'c88cc53549bec0e9f246f056dc05a745',
        artist: artist,
        track: track,
        format: 'json',
        },
  dataType: 'jsonp', //must be JSONP for CORS
  error: lstError, 
  success: getLastfm
  });
}



/* success: parse album XML from LastFM scrobbler */
function getLastfm(json) {

//alert(json.track.wiki.summary); // wiki summary
var lstError = (typeof json.error === "string")
            ? json.error
            : '';

var lstArtist = (typeof json.track.artist.name === "string")
            ? json.track.artist.name
            : '';
var lstTitle = (typeof json.track.name === "string")
            ? json.track.name
            : '';
var lstAlbumart = (typeof json.track.album.image[3]['#text'] === "string")
            ? json.track.album.image[3]['#text']
            : '';
var lstAlbum = (typeof json.track.album.title === "string")
            ? json.track.album.title
            : '';
var lstWikis = (typeof json.track.wiki.summary === "string")
            ? json.track.wiki.summary
            : '';
```

Comment: Where are the logic checks your talking about? I only see the variable declarations.